# Setting detailed/customer error messages issues, iis7 asp classic

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I haven't been able to find a similar problem anywhere. Basically when I set the site to custom errors it displays the default 500 error message, however when I then set it to show detailed errors the page loads fine without error. Has anyone else come across this? How can I see what the error is?

Answer (score 2):

**IN IIS**

1. Open the IIS7 manager
2. Select the Website and on its features view, double click on “Error Pages”.
3. Right click and select the “Edit Feature Settings…” or select the same from the Actions pane (in the right hand side)
4. Select the “Detailed errors” radio button and click on OK
5. Now, your client browsers will be able to see the detailed error messages.

ALSO...

Click on the website in content view. Go to "ASP" under the "Debugging Properties" make sure "Send errors to browser" is set to true.

**IN CONTROL PANEL**

Internet Options > Advanced (tab) > Un-tick "Show Friendly HTTP error messages"

Comment: Why **Un-tick "Show Friendly HTTP error messages"** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: because that setting takes the valuable information your server transmits ("syntax error on line 345" or whatever), throws it out the window, and shows you a page that says, effectively, "an error occurred, but I'm not telling you where or when. Here are some totally useless things you could try, like refreshing the page."

Answer (score 2):

By default IIS7 intercepts HTTP status codes such as 4xx and 5xx generated by applications further up the pipeline.

In web.config replace the line

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
```

with

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed">
```