# How to get IIS 8.5 to send detailed error messages?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8.5

We are trying to run a classic .asp application on Windows 2012 IIS 8.5. ASP scripts work in general but when there is an error (e.g. include missing or syntax) then we simply see:

```
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. 
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
```

This although we have enabled detailed error messages on the site and regardless of whether we run the application remotely or via localhost.

We want to know which script and line of code is causing the problem.

We've also tried routing 500 errors to an error handling .asp page which can provide error details to no avail.

PS: There also seems to be no "ASP" feature so no way to enable debugging or the like.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5912873/65775. To get the ASP feature in IIS you need to add it via Server Manager > Add Roles and Features.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detailed 500 error message, ASP + IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5)

Answer (score 2):

Please carefully follow below steps:

Step 1: **Check Classic ASP is installed on your server**

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTeBnLzP_FY

Double click "ASP" in middle section under IIS

Enable Parent Paths: True

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default

Step 2: **Check IIS setting**
Select your website under IIS - 
Goto "Edit Permissions..." under Actions pane (top right)
Make sure that folder has correct permissions

Step 3: **Application Pool**

Goto application pool in IIS manager

Select application pool used by Classic ASP website

Under Advance settings

.Net Framework Version : v2.0

Enable 32-Bit Applications: True

Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated

Identity: NetworkService

This steps resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Keith for the useful tip. The missing key in my case was the icon for the ASP feature. You have to start the IIS Manager using "Run as Administrator" before you see this. Once you have that you can enable "Send Errors to Browser" as described in the link provided above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5912873/65775

Comment: Thanks for the tip to 'Run as Administrator'. I am on Azure VM and had to do this to get the ASP icon to show up.